# Add custom phtml file before the category filter in Magento2

Tags: magento2, phtml, sidebar

I am trying to add custom file in left navigation before the filters.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seotext_sidebar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/seotext.phtml" before="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

the above code appears after the filters but not before the filters.

how can i load custom file before the filters. I need to move breadcrumbs to left navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`before="-"`

to

```
before="catalog.leftnav"
```

See what happen.

As `before="-"` is count as the first level of this section, and you want
 change block position to before it then you have put `catalog.leftnav` in `before` tag

Comment: @jafarpinjar Then you should mark as accepted which will help future readers :)

Comment: @AdityaShah, how to move this outside the content, like before the footer

Answer (score 0):

you can add like this also in your layout default.xml or else in your theme  catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <referenceBlock  name="catalog.leftnav" >
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seotext_sidebar" 
                  template="Magento_Catalog::product/seotext.phtml" before="-">
          </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```